# False complaining for SQL Injection

Tags: prepared-statement, sql-injection, sonarqube-scan

I'm using a java code. I'm using prepared statement with no concatenation. But still I'm getting SQL injection complaint by SonarQube. Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error?

Code :

```
HashMap<String, String> query = [some source for hashmap];
String sql = (String) query.get(key);
stmt = conn.preparedstatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, param1);
```

Comment: Well, what's in the hashmap? Was that created from safe content? Can SonarQube verify every element of the hashmap?

Comment: I'm passing some external xmls into it. Which are having key as some query name and values as SQL query but those are in child jars not in main jar

Comment: How do you know the SQL query in the external XML is safe? Certainly SonarQube cannot know that. So it must assume they are potentially not safe.

Comment: So can I mark it as fixed. Or is there any solution so that sonar automatically stopped complaining about this

Comment: If you know the content in the XML file is completely under your control, and no untrusted content can sneak into it, then I suppose it's safe. But I have no experience with SonarQube, so I don't know what options are available.